# HTML binding angular 2.0.0-beta.0

Tags: angular

I would like to bind the variable with HTML syntax into a template. However, it seems the inner-html directive does not work in the angular 2.0.0-beta.0. For example:

```
<p [inner-html]="item.content"></p>
```

What is the new alternative way or syntax in angular 2.0.0-beta.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In alpha.52 Angular templates were changed to be case-sensitive and with this the selectors of all directives.

Use instead

```
<p [innerHTML]="item.content"></p>
```

see also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha52-2015-12-10

Comment: This is working for me now. Thanks!